# Not to Show Add-in error message if it is not installed

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, custom-functions-excel

I have developed an Excel Add-in, which uses shared runtime. Now when I save a workbook after opening Add-in, it inserts add-in information in it and if I send it to someone who does not have Add-in, it shows error message that You don't have add-in rights or similar. I have to manually remove Add-in using Info=>Inspect for Issues option.

Is there any way that I can removed or prevent Add-in information from workbook? As per documentation there are scenarios like one [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document#:%7E:text=For%20example%2C%20a%20student%20who%20uses%20a%20dictionary%20add%2Din%20in%20a%20Word%20document%20might%20not%20want%20their%20classmates%20or%20teachers%20to%20be%20prompted%20to%20install%20that%20add%2Din%20when%20they%20open%20the%20document.:%7E:text=For%20example%2C%20a%20student%20who%20uses%20a%20dictionary%20add%2Din%20in%20a%20Word%20document%20might%20not%20want%20their%20classmates%20or%20teachers%20to%20be%20prompted%20to%20install%20that%20add%2Din%20when%20they%20open%20the%20document.) in MS documentation.

I have tried to achieve it using one of the following, but it is not working. Do I missing something here?

```
Office.addin.setStartupBehavior(Office.StartupBehavior.none);
```

2

```
Office.context.document.settings.set("Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument", false);
Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync();
```

3

```
Office.context.document.settings.remove('Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument');
Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync();
```

None of the above 3 worked in my case.

Comment: I don't think its possible, but I'd also appreciate this feature! Let me know if you figure a way out! Currently, I just copy data to a new worksheet when I'm sending data externally, quite annoying really.